# How to make drush to work correctly in Windows?

Tags: 7, drush

In Linux drush is comfortable with all Linux native commands. But how to make it working in Windows?

Of course there is a drush installer for Windows and it is correct, but the real question is: how to make all commands to work correctly?

For example `drush sql-dump` returns this error:

```
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal command
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you're trying to ask how to get drush working in windows.

If you consult the documentation there is a [windows installer](https://github.com/drushonwindows/Drush-on-Windows-Installer):

> The Drush Windows Installer provides a convenient way to install Drush
>   and the components it needs in order to run on Microsoft Windows. You
>   may download it from the attachments list at the bottom of this page.
>   Please see the installation guide below for instructions on how to run
>   the installer.

Furthermore, if you're trying to get drush working before 5.7 there's a [manual installation guide](http://groups.drupal.org/node/265678) if you need to:

> The Drush Make command does not work in Windows 7 / Vista, when using
>   Drush release 5.5, 5.6, or 5.7. However, the current development
>   version of Drush fixes this issue! The only problem is there is no
>   windows installer program for this version.
>
> No worries. This article provides instructions for manually installing
>   the latest development version of Drush in Windows.

**Update:**

> For example drush sql-dump returns this error :
>
> 'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal command

This is a seperate and non-drupal issue. This is caused because drush doesn't know the path to mysql.exe. You need to update your paths in order for msqldump to work. Search super user or stackoverflow regarding mysql, windows and or path together in order to get an answer. I used to know this but it's been too many moons.

Answer (score 5):

To make drush sql-dump work on Windows, verify that the PATH environment variable includes mysql binaries. Locate the Environment Variables dialog, for Windows 7 right-click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> click Environment Variables button. Under System variables select Path variable, click Edit and at the end of Varable value: field add the path to your mysql binaries.

For example, if you use WampServer, the typical location for mysql binaries is at

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
```

and let's say your Path variable contains these paths:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

Mind that the paths are separated by ';' and there is no need of quotes if your path contains spaces. After your modification the Path variable should contain

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin
```

If the Path variable doesn't exist, go ahead and create one.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using XAMPP so I added `;C:\xampp\mysql\bin`

Comment: It is not working for me.